# Calculating Combinations for a string

Tags: statistics, combinations

Say you have a string ABCD where A can take any of 4 values, B can take any of 5 values, C can take any of 3 values, and D can take any of 8 values.

How would I calculate the combinations?

I'm fairly certain its not nCr where n is the number of classes (4) and r is the total cases (20). Would it be (4!)(5!)(3!)(8!) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A, B, C, and D are independent, so it would be just $4\cdot 5\cdot 3\cdot 8=480$.

If A, B, C, and D can be interchanged, then multiply this result by $4!$ to get the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I don't understand the second part. I believe they are independent though.

Comment: As in if you have ABDC, ACBD, ACDB, etc.